# Unable to load FormsFlow Web

Tags: formsflow.ai, formsflow

I have configured all the required modules, but while loading the FormsFlow Web, I see the page is not loading at all. Attached image with inspection window. Can you please suggest what might be going wrong here

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your environment variable KEYCLOAK_URL is missing.  [According to README mentioned here](https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai/tree/master/deployment/docker) update environment variable by referring the [sample.env](https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai/blob/master/deployment/docker/sample.env).

After updating your environment variables ensure to rebuild the containers with command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-windows.yml up --build -d
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be due to the missing Keycloak env. And Remember to Redeploy your app after Environment change.
Check the Keycloak Env in the below line is added.

https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai/blob/5555c1b2a9a5496f1ab98e5339d66537e25974c2/deployment/docker/sample.env#L49

Refer this issue which is similar.

https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai/issues/182